# Using Newtons method to optimize a non convex function

Tags: newton-raphson, hessian-matrix, non-convex-optimization

I want to use newtons method to find the local solutions of a non convex function. I have studied that the hessian must be positive definite to find the solution using newtons method. Can I use newtons method to find local solution of a non convex function as for this function hessian may be negative definite or indefinite as well.

Comment: You should probably better explain your question. What are the hypotheses? What are the domain and codomain of your function? Is it twice continuously differentiable? You have mixed tags in your question.

Comment: As in newtons method for optimization, we need to have the hessian to be positive definite. But this is not possible in case of non convex function as hessian can be negative definite or indefinite. Can I use newtons method to find the local solutions without the hessian being positive definite?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: If the Hessian contains both positive and negative eigenvalues, then it necessarily corresponds to a saddle point. However, if the Hessian of $f$ is not positive definite at a point, it is still possible for the point to be a local extremum (say, if its eigenvalues are nonnegative).

Comment: so while using newtons method for non convex function, one should make sure the hessian is either positive definite or negative definite.

And if in case our starting guess lands on the saddle point, what can we do about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question, I assume that the objective is to minimize a non-convex function.

The problem with using Newton's method to minimize a non-convex function is that it does not distinguish between different types of stationary points (points of zero gradient): local maxima, local minima or saddle points. For instance, consider the non-convex 1-d function $f(x)= -x^2$ (in fact, it is concave), which has a maximum at $x=0$. One iteration of Newton's method takes you directly to the maximum.

In higher dimensions, this behavior is due to the presence of directions of negative curvature of the Hessian. By this, I mean directions pointed to by eigenvectors corresponding to negative eigenvalues. For this reason, the applicability of Newton's method is restricted to cases where the Hessian is positive definite.

There exist variants of Newton's method to minimize non-convex functions. See, for example, the [Gauss-Newton algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm) or the [Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm). While these algorithms have been historically proposed for the non-linear least squares problem, the ideas can be applied more generally to non-convex optimization.